# eth.sendTransaction submits, but doesn't add to contract balance or trigger fallback function

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ether

I have tried sending 0.06 Ether to a contract as follows:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: "0x76E15697E36a66BF977D35de3C488F10B8014e65", value: web3.toWei(0.06, "ether")})
```

I've also tried sending 0.03 to the same contract address via MetaMask. However, although sending ether via `eth.sendTransaction()` through the geth command line submits, and on Etherscan no problems are shown, it doesn't add to a contract balance or trigger the fallback function (unlike sending Ether through MetaMask).

The contract in question is https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x76e15697e36a66bf977d35de3c488f10b8014e65

I'm trying this on the Rinkeby test network (not sure if it's a bug with this).

Comment: MetaMask don't support calls without callbacks, maybe that's the issue here?
Try with callback function as last parameter

Comment: One more thing... I had similar symptoms when Metamask Chrome plugin was locked. Try to click on Metamask icon and enter password first.

Comment: Please post some code fragments from your contract, especially regarding fallback function. maybe the issue is with your Solidity code

Comment: the issue is not with metamask, but the `eth.sendTransaction` in geth not adding to the contract balance - I can't see why certain code would work only with sending ether with metamask but not through geth